# integer of arbitrary base division, without conversion to base 10

Tags: algorithm, division, radix, integer-division

Integers are represented as a list of ints, for example:

- [13, 2] (D2 in base 16)
- [1, 3, 6] (136 in base 10)

We are only allowed to use the digits separately, they cannot be converted to base 10 integers.

I wanted to implement division in '**paper & pencil**' aka '**long division**' way, but it turns out that
it requires the divisor and dividend prefixes to be base 10 integers to be able to perform base 10 integer division.

for example:
to find 11131 / 117, we need to first find 1113 / 117

**Is there any way to decompose a division like 1113 / 117 into smaller steps, which won't require any divisions other than such that the divisor is in a closed range [1, base - 1]?**

**Is there any other way to perform this division not in the 'paper & pencil' way?**

Comment: Things you need to be able to do: subtract, compare, multiply a multi-digit number by a single-digit number. To find `1113 / 117` in base B, perform a binary search in the range [1, B-1]. For each attempt multiply 117 by the candidate digit, and compare with 1113. After finding the largest digit D such that `117 * D <= 1113` subtract 117 * D from 1113. Then continue with the next step of long division.

Comment: You don't need base 10 division. Paper-and-pensil works the same way in any base.

Comment: @user58697 I think u missed the point of my problem. I cannot perform any division with a divisor outside of [1, base - 1] independently of the base, because it would require me to convert the list of ints into a single number, which I'm not allowed to do. Base 10 division is also the only one available on a typical int implementation, apart from bit shifts

Comment: @user3386109 I'm looking for a more 'direct' solution, but the one u proposed is actually correct, so thank you

Comment: I don't understand the significance of base 10 in this question. Most computers represent numbers in base 2.

Comment: We are not allowed to convert bases and thus we are limited to divisions by divisors in [1, base - 1] by the problem definition itself. Also independently of the base of a number, each digit is represented by a base 10 int. So that's where base 10 significance comes from.

Comment: An int is stored in base 2. It may be displayed in base 10 as the default representation when you choose to print it out for your own viewing as a programmer.

Comment: What we *can* say is that we are given the digits of the number separately.

Comment: I agree with the last comment but I suppose that the previous one missed the point, when I said: "each digit is represented by a base 10 int", I meant the actual representation in the code we can work with, not the internal.